# How can I render 2 items in a FlatList in React-native and Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I need to render two items "clientcalendarscreenred" and "nutritiondata" in a FlatList

PS:  I am getting the two data "clientcalendarscreenred" and "nutritiondata" from a reducer through mapStateToProps

---

```
<FlatList

               data={this.props.clientcalendarscreenred }

               keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}

               renderItem={this._renderItem}

               ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}

               refreshing={this.state.refreshing}

               onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
        />
```

===========
                 GETTING The DATA
    ===============

```
const mapStateToProps = ({clientcalendarscreenred, maincalendarreducer}) => {

  const { client_id, workout_date, display_date } = maincalendarreducer;

   return { 

        clientcalendarscreenred: clientcalendarscreenred.data,
        nutritiondata: clientcalendarscreenred.nutrition,
    };


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use section list for this scenario.
You can also render the list heterogeneous or homogeneous i.e if you wish to render your sections differently

`<SectionList renderSectionHeader={({section}) => this._renderHeader(section.data)}
                         sections={[
                           {
                             key: 'RedData',
                             data: clientcalendarscreenred.data,
                             renderItem: ({item}) => this.renderRedData(item)
                           },
                           {
                             key: 'NutritionData',
                             data: clientcalendarscreenred.nutrition,
                             renderItem: ({item}) => this.renderNutrition(item, index, section)
                           },
                         ]}
                         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            />`

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work for you to print items from data prop in FlatList.Similarly you can pass nutritiondata to FlatList and use it to display.

```
const FlatList=(props)=>{
const {data, ...rest}=props;
const toRender= data&&data.length>0?data.map(item=><div>{item.something}</div>:<div/>
return toRender
}
```